# Getting fatal error LNK1104 qgis build

Tags: qgis, windows-7, library, compile

I try to build qgis1.8.0 using Microsoft Visual c++ 2010 in a Windows 7 64bit.
all the dependency are installed and the solution qgis1.8.0.sln was generated succesfully.
but my problem is the appearence of those when i build the solution:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   '....\core\RelWithDebInfo\qgis_core.lib fatal error LNK1104: cannot
>   open file '....\providers\grass\RelWithDebInfo\qgisgrass.lib fatal
>   error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   '....\analysis\RelWithDebInfo\qgis_analysis.lib

Does anybody know how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case. I tryed to build qgis in a Windows 64bit machine.however
,because of the non compatibility of OSGEO libraries in qgis source with the system, I wasn't able to build thebinary from the source.
Then i decided to run the build in a windows 32bit machine and it was done successfully.